# Difference between a single line and association line in UML

Tags: uml, domain-driven-design, associations

I have the following class diagrams taken from a book 
[image: UML diagrams]
In Figure 6.4 there is a plain line between part and purchase order
line item. Whereas in figure 6.11 there is an arrow from 
purchase order line item to part 
What's the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Figure 6.4 there is a plain line between part and purchase order
> line item

in this figure the relation is (probably) navigable in the two directions, that means *Part* and *Purchage Order Line Item* reference/know each other

Typically the class *Purchage Order Line Item* has an attribute of type *Part*, and the class *Part* has an attribute of type *Purchage Order Line Item* (the multiplicities are not indicated, let say they are both 1 else they are collection of).

This is the case E-F in figure 11.29 *Examples of navigable association-owned ends* page 205 of [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML)

> in figure 6.11 there is an arrow from purchase order line item to part

In this diagram the relation is navigable in only one direction, *Purchage Order Line Item* reference/know the *Part* but *Part* does not know/reference the *Purchage Order Line Item* knowing/referencing it

Typically the class *Purchage Order Line Item* has an attribute of type *Part*, but the class *Part* does not have an attribute of type *Purchage Order Line Item* (the multiplicities are not indicated, let say they are both 1 else they are collection of).

This is the case I-J in figure 11.29 *Examples of navigable association-owned ends* page 205 of [formal/2017-12-05](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML)

Comment: For figure 6.4 does `When the PO is deleted or archived, the line items are taken along` holds ? I have taken this from the book Domain Driven Design book. But I am not sure why the design in figure 6.11 is better and how it preserves the invariant

Comment: @MonuDidi `When the PO is deleted or archived, the line items are taken along` about archived it is not possible to know that, for deleted it is only sure in case of a composition, but here there is no composition in both diagram, only aggregation in the second case. The second is better at least because the PO memorizes the price through POLI (price get when the PO is made) => if later the price of an item changes the PO is unchanged as it must be

Comment: So it's like PO has it's unique copy of POLI and POLI has a unique copy of price and quantity. So the price of an item cannot change outside PO. ie. one cannot edit the item price as the reference to it is inside POLI and not available outside.  So what I understand is there is a list of parts with a price for each part. And when POLI is made it includes the price at that time from the part object. Whereas in figure 6.4 it holds a reference to the part so if the part price changes it will get changes in POLI which is undesirable

Comment: Yes. A part's price can change at any time at its level. In 6.4 the PO price is computed from each part price so if a part's price changes the PO price change too, this is not expected. Thanks to the copy of the part's price in POLI in second diagram that problem disappears. The goal of the aggregation in the second diagram is to say a POLI is own by a PO, so a POLI cannot be shared by several PO

Comment: Thanks. So when we talk about aggregator pattern. It seems like there is a root object that keeps a copy of child-objects and so once the root object is constructed the changes to the child-objects are not propagated inside root-object.. just like in the bottom figure. That seems like one main point of aggregator pattern.. Am I correct here ?